# Cannot kill a process after waking it up

Tags: linux, process, signal

I ran the program `yes` and pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to stop the process.

After that, I woke it up by executing `kill -s 18 <pid>`.

After that, I wasn't able to stop it again using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or kill it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about how shells and terminals cooperate to manage foreground and background processes. This is what happened:

You run `yes` in an interactive shell. The shell spawned `yes` in a separate process group<sup>1</sup>. The shell informed the terminal (terminal emulator) the new process group is now in the foreground. The term is *foreground process group*. The shell remained in its own process group that stopped being the foreground process group. The shell ceased reading from the terminal, effectively putting itself in the background.

Upon <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> the terminal sends [`SIGSTP`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/410088/108618) to the foreground process group. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is similar: the signal is `SIGINT` but it also goes to the foreground process group.

In your case `SIGSTP` was sent to the `yes` process. The process stopped and its parent (i.e. the shell) received `SIGCHLD`, so it could react. The shell reacted by informing the terminal the new foreground process group is the one of the shell. The shell resumed reading from the terminal. This way it put itself in the foreground. It printed the prompt and let you interact.

Then you executed `kill -s 18 …` and sent `SIGCONT` to the `yes` process<sup>2</sup>.

After receiving `SIGCONT` the `yes` process continued. It was still in the background, i.e. its process group did not become the foreground process group. It printed to the console like when it was in the foreground<sup>3</sup>. The whole situation was as if you put the stopped `yes` to the background with `bg` or run it in the background as `yes &` in the first place.

The shell remained in the foreground. Your tries with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> kept making the terminal send `SIGSTP` and `SIGINT` to the shell. Upon `SIGINT` your shell probably printed `^C` and rewrote the prompt, but because of `yes` printing very fast (and your terminal scrolling very fast) you did not notice.

And you probably didn't notice you can type commands in the shell. If you typed `fg`<kbd>Enter</kbd>, the shell would inform the terminal the process group of `yes` is the new foreground process group. The shell would background itself, just like immediately after you invoked `yes`. *Then* you would be able to send `SIGSTP` or `SIGINT` to the `yes` process by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Try it.

---

<sup>1</sup> Simple shells or non-interactive shells (where there is no job control) may run everything in their process group. What you experienced indicates `yes` was spawned in a separate process group though.

<sup>2</sup> In Linux it depends on the architecture what exact signal the number 18 means (see `man 7 signal`). By your description I can tell it was `SIGCONT` (you can confirm this by examining the output of `kill -l`). In general [POSIX connects few numbers to specific signals](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html), but 18 is not among these numbers and `SIGCONT` is not among these signals. The most portable way to send `SIGCONT` is with `kill -s CONT`, not with a number. This should work on any POSIX-compliant (or almost POSIX-compliant) OS.

<sup>3</sup> A processes in the background usually can write to its controlling terminal; it cannot read from it. Investigate [`SIGTTOU` and `SIGTTIN`](http://curiousthing.org/sigttin-sigttou-deep-dive-linux) for details, I won't elaborate here.

Comment: Just a comment to say how thorough this answer is. I liked it!

Comment: Thanks, helped a lot!